# Как удалить используемый файл

Tags: c#, windows

Я пишу на C# программу, которая с помощью библиотеки log4net ведет лог в отдельный файл. Когда лог-файл переполняется, он должен быть удален. Но, к сожалению, из-за того, что этот файл открыт в приложении, я не могу его удалить. При вызове метода `File.Delete` из класса `System.IO.File` ничего не происходит, файл не удаляется, а лог продолжает записываться. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: а что значит *файл переполняется*?

Comment: Я немного не корректно написал. Это просто произвольный размер в байтах, который задает пользователь, по превышению которого требуется удалить файл.

Comment: log4net, как и другие умные логеры может сам следить за размером лога, и чистить его, бить по размерам, это называеся log rotation, можно моного чего наконфигурировать, и не велосипедить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в config файл:

```
<lockingmodel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
```

Это должно помочь разлочить файл для удаления.

Answer (score 7):

А зачем вы проводите такие манипуляции в коде, когда log4net [умеет это делать из коробки](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html)?

```
<maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
```